# Programmatically Open Windows 8 Bluetooth Control Panel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, bluetooth

Back in Win7 and prior, I used to just be able to do this in C#:

```
Process.Start("control", "bthprops.cpl");
```

However, in Windows 8.0 and 8.1 while that code DOES still work, it more often just dumps you to the Devices control panel instead of specifically the Bluetooth panel (it's inconsistent and unreliable).

I was able to find a nifty tutorial on how to create a shortcut on your desktop that opens the Bluetooth Control Panel directly, however I've tried many permutations with `Process.Start()` and have been unable to get this to work in my app:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/36102-bluetooth-devices-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html

When I create the shortcut per the tutorial on my Win8 box it works like a charm every time. Please note I'm looking to implement the first solution which opens the Windows RT/WinStore/ModernUI control panel for Bluetooth, not the "Desktop Mode" control panel.

I'm looking to open the Bluetooth control panel programmatically using C# and .Net inside a WPF app.

Comment: I currently have a ticket in with the Win8 Apps Evangelist team for an answer on this, but nothing has been forthcoming yet. I will add the answer here once I get one, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code given by the Microsoft TAM to solve the issue is as follows:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%localappdata%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPagePCSystemBluetooth.settingcontent-ms");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Note that the "en-US" folder would need to be replaced with the current locale information in order to provide internationalization! (Language packs also required.)

However, they claim that the former solution should also work reliably:

```
Process.Start("control", "bthprops.cpl");
```

I will continue working with Microsoft to determine why the simpler solution does not work reliably, however the code above provides a work-around in the meantime.